# displaying fractions in angular js webapp

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, windows, web-applications

How do I get the numerator in the fraction displayed to go up by one each time a player is selected?

Secondly, how do I stop users from being able to select players once the $50 , 000, 000 limit is passed or 6 players have been selected.

I tried putting a fraction from "0/6" up to "6/6" as a string but it seems inefficient. Help

This is the link to the index:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDRFSHK2WONU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your "$scope.buy" function, modify the "$scope.playersSelected" as needed.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playersSelected = "0/6";
  $scope.total = 50000000;
  //keep trak of what was bought already
  $scope.history = [];
  $scope.players = [{
      name: "Yasin 'YB' Amusan",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Femi 'Fabio' Awoniyi",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Deji 'Dej' Awoniyi",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Koye 'K10' Kekere-Ekun",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Teni 'Teezee' Zacchaeus",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Bolaji 'Boj' Odojukan",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Ernest",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Fikayo 'Kyo' Etti",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'Defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Efe Tunde-Imoyo",
      Team: "Industry",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Temi 'Forbes' Afolabi",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 14000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Dami Etomi",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Tomi 'Belg' Belgore",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Tobi 'Staxx' Kasali",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'Hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Bobo",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'Hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Ola Adeyemi",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Pekun 'Pyzzle' Odutola",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'Hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Oreva 'Revz' Amata",
      Team: "VGC",
      price: 11000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Tenny 'TK' Karim",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'Forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Andy Inegbese",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'Midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Donald 'DO' Ofik",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Zachy Mbadiwe",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 10000000,
      position: 'Forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Emeke 'Mexxo'",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Ife 'I-Baxx Bakare",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Gabriel 'Gabby' Inegbese",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'Hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Jimi Oyelola",
      Team: "YMFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'Forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Chad 'Chadea' Oyefolu",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'Forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Ekoh 'Starboy' Sagoe",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 15000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Tomiwa 'JBET' Jaiyeola",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 13000000,
      position: 'Forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Lemar Chris",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 9000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Olumide 'Olic' Williams",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Leke 'LVD' Dokomu",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Dola Awosika",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Nehemiah 'Memphis'",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Kola 'Skippo' Ayanwale",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 10000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Milekan 'Mileks'",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Lanre 'Lavigz' Vigo",
      Team: "ChadFC",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Alfred 'Flyz' Obande",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Chuka 'Zingy' Azinge",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'hybrid',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Osobase 'Oso' OmoKhodion",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 10000000,
      position: 'midfielder',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Arnold Okuguni",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 7000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Ikenna Mbadiwe",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Moukhtar",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Chinedu 'Anuxx' Anukwem",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 8000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Tosan 'Mac' Wiltshere",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 6000000,
      position: 'defender',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    },
    {
      name: "Martin Agbaso",
      Team: "FBGFC",
      price: 5000000,
      position: 'forward',
      image: src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'
    }
  ];

  $scope.buy = function(i) {
    var p = $scope.history.indexOf(i);
    //if bought, cancel it
    if (p !== -1) {
      $scope.history.splice(p, 1);
      $scope.total += $scope.players[i].price;
    } else {
      //else add it to history
      if ($scope.total < $scope.players[i].price) {
        return;
      }
      $scope.history.push(i);

      $scope.total -= $scope.players[i].price;

      $scope.playersSelected = $scope.history.length + "/6";
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>TNF FANTASY</title>
</head>


<div class="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="total"><i>  <h4> Money Remaining: <br>{{total |currency}}</h4></i>
    <h4>{{playersSelected}}</h4>

  </div>

  <ul>
    <li class="players" ng-repeat="player in players">


      {{player.name}} <br> {{player.Team}} <br> {{player.price| currency}} <br> {{player.position| uppercase }}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="buy($index)">buy</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Replace `{{playersSelected}}` with `{{history.length}}/6`

2) In your buy function under 'add it to history', check you do not have 6 already and the price is not more than the total.

```
$scope.buy = function(i) {

  var p;

  // check if already bought
  if ((p = $scope.history.indexOf(i)) !== -1) {

    // already bought so cancel it
    $scope.history.splice(p, 1);
    $scope.total += $scope.players[i].price;

  } else {
   alert($scope.history.length);
    // check we do not have 6 already
    if ($scope.history && $scope.history.length > 5) {
      return;
    }

    // check the price does not exceed the total left over
    if ($scope.players[i].price > $scope.total) {
      return;
    }

    // add to history
    $scope.history.push(i);
    $scope.total -= $scope.players[i].price;

  }
```